# Payment Gateway Integration API Directory

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, payment-gateway, api

I downloaded PayU Integration API php files to be used in EE2, but I am not too sure in which directory to store it? It's not a module or something similar, its just 3 API files I need to reference in my checkout steps. Where would be best to store them in my EE2 project?

Comment: I summise from your other post at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/23545/store-submit-button-not-redirecting that you're using Expresso Store so I've tagged this accordingly so you get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise that you built it into an Omnipay gateway.

Omnipay is the payment provider library that powers Exp:resso Store 2 and so by building it for Omnipay it will work on Store.

They have a GitHub with examples and documentation https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay

If you decide to go down that route, the ExpressionEngine Answers website wouldn't be the place to get help. Instead you can use StackOverflow with the tag "omnnipay" and they'll be able to assist there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/omnipay

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should use them to create a plugin but technically you can place them wherever you wish so long as whatever needs to reference them can reach them.