# Store Submit Button Not Redirecting

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

I am having trouble with my submit buttons on my expresso store forms. It does not 'recognise' the next attribute in the checkout tag. I.E. I need to click on PLACE YOUR ORDER on my last checkout step to pay for the items, but nothing responds.

```
{exp:store:checkout next="./payu/payu-enterprise-doTransaction-using-soap.php" 
payment_method="Dummy" 
return="store/order/ORDER_HASH" 
<!--secure="yes"--> 
error_handling="inline"}
```

Above is my code for the checkout form. The actual form (not using form tag) is underneath this with control names and values.

When I click on `<input type="submit" name="next" value="PLACE YOUR ORDER" class="button alert" />`, it does not respond at all.

Am I perhaps missing something?

Comment: Try removing "<!--secure="yes"-->" from your tag code.

Comment: Also try removing `error_handling="inline"` which would cause the page to refresh without submitting if you have an error and don't have the proper markup for the error in your template.

Comment: I already tried removing everything to only have the 'next' attribute, but still does nothing..

Comment: As an aside, the `payu/payu-enterprise-doTransaction-using-soap.php` part isn't particularly good practice. Have you considered making Payu an Omnipay payment provider so it works natively in Expresso? https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that your form is submitting to hidden a php script ,If this is so this is incorrect because now you are not processing you tags with any of stores/EE methods unless you are doing some magic inside your script that allows the stores/EE tags to be parsed.

You have to submit your form to the next ee template and not a custom script.

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If this is the last step of the checkout as you mention then you shouldn't have a `next` parameter in there as there is no next step. The `next` and `return` parameters can never co-exist in the same checkout tag as there's either another step to come in the a multi-step checkout process or it's the end of the line and you need to tell store where they should be sent for their order confirmation.

Also, you'll need to ensure to the name of your submit button is changed accordingly. So on the last step of the checkout, instead of calling it `next` you need to call it `submit`:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="PLACE YOUR ORDER" class="button alert" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, I tried this, but still no luck. In all of my checkout steps the same problem occurs. So at the moment I'm just using an <a> tag to go between steps, but this is obviously not the way to go.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. In addition to the two issues mentioned above along with the PHP page in the next parameter it seems that there are potentially a few issues in your templates. Do you have this online somewhere? Can I log in and take a look at the template code? I'll follow-up via email.